# wpdb::prepare() isn't working

Tags: query, wpdb

Here's my code:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'product_codes';

// Check if codes exist
$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM %s", $table_name ); 
$existing_data = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

// Returns empty array despite data existing
print '<pre>';
print_r( $existing_data );
print '</pre>';
```

If I enter the table name literally, it works. If I print out the table name variable, it shows the correct string. But for some reason when I use the code above, I get an empty array - zero results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that in My/SQL table names are not strings. So `'wp_product_codes'` is being interpreted as a string instead of as an actual table. This is why you usually don't see tables passed into `wpdb::prepare()` - you should know the table names as they won't change where `wpdb::prepare()` is meant for data that you may not know / can't be trusted and needs to be sanitized. So let's modify the query:

```
$existing_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}product_codes" );
printf( '<pre>%1$s</pre>', print_r( $existing_data, 1 ) );
die();
```